# How to make QWebEngineView go fullscreen?

Tags: c++, qt, fullscreen, qtwebengine, qt5.8

I have the following code, and I want to make my `QWebEngineView` (Qt 5.8) to go full screen.

My `WebView` class is contained in a `QTabWidget`, so it just fills up the tab, not entire screen.

How can I make it go fullscreen?

```
class WebView:public QObject{
    void acceptFullScreen(QWebEngineFullScreenRequest request){
        request.accept();
    }

public:
    char* home_page;
    QWebEngineView* view=new QWebEngineView();
    WebView(char* page=(char*)"file:///home/tarptaeya/Desktop/Crusta_Prototype_python/about.html"){
        this->home_page=page;
        createWebView();
        this->view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::FullScreenSupportEnabled,true);
        this->view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled,true);
        this->view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows,true);
        connect(this->view->page(),&QWebEnginePage::fullScreenRequested,this,&WebView::acceptFullScreen);
    }
    void createWebView(){
        this->view->load(QUrl(this->home_page));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your widget is inside a tab, then it can't be full screen directly. You have two options:

- Remove it from the tab when you want to make it fullscreen (for example, if you have a *fullscreen* button) and make it a standalone widget. Insert it back into the `QTabWidget` when quitting the fullscreen mode.
- Make the `QTabWidget` to fulfill the screen.

In both cases you can use something like this to make it occupy the whole screen:

```
// Replace the 0 with the screen index
const auto windowGeometry = qApp->desktop()->availableGeometry(0);
widget.move(windowGeometry.topLeft());
widget.resize(windowGeometry.size());
```

It will fulfill the screen but will keep the taskbar visible (in my experience this is highly recommended, so the user can easily switch to other tasks). If you want to cover it, just use `geometry()` instead of the `availableGeometry()` method.

**EDIT** in both cases the widget will have the windows manager frame. If you want to remove it you may try setting the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` flag. Take into consideration that removing frame may also make some actions unavailable (at least on Windows) such as moving, resizing, snapping...

Comment: I found your answer useful  , meanwhile I found other method to do the same (which i posted as answer) , could you please tell me if there is some mistake in my posted answer, Thanks

Comment: Your're right! I forgot that one (the [`showFullScreen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showFullScreen), which is basically the second option using the full geometry of the desktop, although fullscreen widgets may be handled differently (see documentation about X11).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this ,so I am answering my own question :
I can change the `acceptFullScreen` function as :

```
void acceptFullScreen(QWebEngineFullScreenRequest request){
        if(request.toggleOn()){
            request.accept();
            QWidget* w=(QWidget*)this->view->parent();
            this->layout=w->layout();
            this->layout->removeWidget(this->view);
            this->view->setParent(0);
            this->view->showFullScreen();
        }
        else{
            request.accept();
            this->layout->addWidget(this->view);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find an easy way to fullscreen. My `QtWebEngineview` is a central widget of the main window, I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to toggle the fullscreen.

1. Enable and connect the signal and slot

   ```
   auto settings = m_webEngineView->settings();
   settings->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::FullScreenSupportEnabled, true);
   QShortcut *fullscreen = new QShortcut(this);
   fullscreen->setKey(Qt::CTRL + Qt::SHIFT + Qt::Key_F11);
   connect(fullscreen, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(onFullScreen()));
   ```
2. `onFullScreen` slot, just toggle the `QtWdiget` window flags

   ```
   void HzWindow::onFullScreen(){
      setWindowState(windowState() ^ Qt::WindowFullScreen);
   }
   ```

That's all I have done.